# Optimize the rate of update. Reduce the DB calls required for the updating the `last_activity` on every API request

Tags: mysql, scala, server, system-design

On every API request, I'm updating the user session `last_activity` in Database.
I'm using `last_activity` information to calculate the number of active users.
How can I reduce the DB update calls on every request. In my application, there were a lot of parallel API calls from Client App.
Is there a way, I can perform `last_activity` update only one in a particular duration.
Skipping that `last_activity` update for other requests arrives in that duration.

Comment: How about seding the last activity to a message channel like Kafka, then do a time windowed grouping on user_ids and update periodically ?

Comment: @sarveshseri That would be a good option but we don't have Kafka in our stack.

Comment: If you are doing more than 100 req/second, you need to evolve your stack to start doing some "not so critical things" in asynchronous manner.

Comment: @sarveshseri Agree on that, But due to some limitations, we can't do it. Is there any way to use a local cache to avoid database calls?

Comment: Yes, if you implement a write-through cache. But then you will have to worry about loosing that cached data and request routing as well.

Answer (score 0):

How often will the Updates occur?  If less than 100/second, then don't worry.  If more, then we can discuss further.

To skip updating if the previous activity was "recent" requires a `SELECT`.  If it is recent, then you get away with one Select (cheaper).  Else you have to do both the Select and the Update (more expensive than just the Update).  Can't win.

Comment: In my case, it might cross the 100 req/second. On every request, First I do update `lastActivity` if an update is successful then only I process the request, In that request, I need to run another query to fetch the required data. 
in case of  `lastActivity` update fail, I unauthorized the user.

Comment: If the disk is SSD, the cutoff is more like 1000/second.  Else, show us the SQL for further critique and optimization.